# Leaf cannot find my template - Xcode 12 Vapor 4

Tags: vapor, xcode12, leaf

I updated from Vapor 3 to 4, and Xcode 11 to 12. Now Leaf cannot find my *.leaf templates. I get a "noTemplateFile" error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://theswiftdev.com/how-to-create-your-first-website-using-vapor-4-and-leaf/

The trick was to add a "Custom Working Directory" in the scheme's options. I added my project's root directory and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Just modify your schema to be the directory for your Vapor server.
Step by step guideline here https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/xcode/